# How we can get "this" for eventResize in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Can someone suggest a solution to get resized event DOM details, like 'this'.

```
eventResize:function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
this.addClass('selected');
this.hasClass('001');   
}
```

Here I want check resized event DOM has a class or need to add class.

Looking like below.

```
eventRender:function(event, element, calEvent) {
element.addClass('selected');   
element.hasClass('selected');
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are binding a jQuery method to a dom node not to a jQuery object, you need to have a jQuery object wrapper `$()`:

```
$(event.target).addClass('selected');
```

*Here I want check resized event DOM has a class or need to add class.*

I am not sure if you meant something like this:

```
eventResize:function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
    if($(event.target).hasClass('001')){
       $(event.target).addClass('selected');
    }   
}
```

Comment: No, it will not work out, As per  your suggestion selected class will reflect for the parent body element. Here just I want apply this for resized DOM.

Comment: @jaison you can then use `$(event.target)`

Comment: No luck, I have edited the question, So you people can more understood